# Can't erase disk, Error: -69760

Tags: disk-format, diskutil

I am trying to format a USB drive, however I am faced with the following error:

```
sh-3.2# diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk3
Forced unmount of all volumes on disk3 was successful
sh-3.2# diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ MacOS /dev/disk3
Started erase on disk3
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device
sh-3.2# lsof | grep disk3
sh-3.2#
```

Could someone help me to figure out what to do to resolve this issue?

EDIT 2:

```
# fdisk -f boothfs /dev/disk3
Disk: /dev/disk3    geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
sh-3.2# fdisk -i -a boothfs /dev/disk3
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory

    -----------------------------------------------------
    ------ ATTENTION - UPDATING MASTER BOOT RECORD ------
    -----------------------------------------------------

Do you wish to write new MBR and partition table? [n] y

sh-3.2# 
sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 7887C476-CBE0-4D10-B95A-5C79F83B20D7
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *1.0 TB     disk3

sh-3.2#
```

EDIT 3 **(In CentOS 7)**

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdc is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
 Warning: could not erase sector 2: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
61054976 inodes, 244190646 blocks
12209532 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=2392850432
7453 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848
Allocating group tables: done                            
Warning: could not read block 0: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:    0/7453
Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.
```

Comment: Thank you, for your edit, I was thinking about my bad question.

Comment: macOS seems to be picky when it comes to formatting drives. Many others have had similar issues, including me. I solved it as follows: I formatted the drive in Windows first and then reformatted it with Disk Utility. Others see the culprit in the connector or cable, i'd recommend that you test with another cable. If possible, test the hard disk in another enclosure.

Comment: @jaume, How to do it (Which Method)? `Format Drive:\ ` or Using `Disk Part` or `Disk Management`? Thanks

Comment: `Disk Management` is the right tool for this job. Launch it, identify the USB drive and erase any existing partitions. Format the drive to NTFS (assign a drive letter and test that it mounts properly). Eject it, plug it in your Mac and format it with Disk Utility. That's the procedure that worked for me, could you try it and report back?

Comment: Thanks I was trying with Windows 7, but is not working...

Comment: What is not working? Can't you erase the partitions? Or do you get an error message (which one) when formatting it with Disk Utility? You may want to try `DISKPART` on Windows to completely erase the disk, see http://www.winability.com/delete-protected-efi-disk-partition/ or `dd` on your Mac, as explained here: https://fossbytes.com/erase-disk-linux-mac/. You could also try formatting the disk to exFAT instead of NTFS.

Comment: Did you resolved this problem? Cause I have the same. Tried to format it in Ubuntu with all methods but still not working.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In the meantime, can I ask you to please not add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can add a comment on the question/answer you wanted to comment on. Alternatively, if you have an answer instead, see [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here. In the meantime I’ve converted your post into a comment on your behalf. :)

Comment: @AlexLexan I have my disk in my table, but I Haven't solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DD command to erase the partition map first. You can do this by unmounting the usb drive in disk utility, checking what the device name is (i.e. `/dev/diskX` where X indicates your devices number or device identifier such as `/dev/disk2`). Otherwise you can use the terminal command `disktil list` to get device identifiers for all of your drives. Then open your terminal app and run the following command (warning this will completely wipe your drive of all data):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/diskX bs=512 count=1
```

Dont forget to replace "X" with the proper device identifier of your inserted usb drive or you could accidentally erase macOS. Usually, if you dont have any other external disks inserted aside from the one you are trying to erase, your identifier would be `/dev/disk2`, but there is no guarentee on that. So be sure to find your proper device identifier.
Then enter your password for your command to complete. Finally, eject your usb drive with disk utility and then plug it back into your mac. A mac popup should say something like "the disk you inserted is not formatted, would your like to format this disk?". Then open up disk utility again or the terminal app and format the drive how you normally would.

If this still doesnt work, then you have a broken usb drive, or, your hard drive cable is shot and you need to buy a new cable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem trying various options on terminal didn't help, eventually just by  luck I went back to disk utility and chose format/MacOS extended journaled and scheme/Apple partition map. After that went for scheme/GUID   This was an absolute fluke after encountering various messages regarding being unable to format the drive. Might not work for everyone but I had exhausted all other avenues.